# Algorithm to create a square matrix given any number of smaller square matrices

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matrix

I will want to plot some images using Opencv, and for this I would like to glue images together.

Imagine I have 4 pictures. The best way would be to glue them in a 2x2 image matrix.

```
a = img; a.shape == (48, 48)
b = img; b.shape == (48, 48)
c = img; c.shape == (48, 48)
d = img; d.shape == (48, 48)
```

I now use the np.reshape which takes a list such as [a,b,c,d], and then I manually put the dimensions to get the following:

```
np.reshape([a,b,c,d], (a.shape*2, a.shape*2)).shape == (96, 96)
```

The issue starts when I have 3 pictures. I kind of figured that I can take the square root of the length of the list and then the ceiling value which will yield the square matrix dimension of 2 (`np.ceil(sqrt(len([a,b,c]))) == 2`). I would then have to add a white image with the dimension of the first element to the list and there we go. But I imagine there must be an easier way to accomplish this for plotting, most likely already defined somewhere.

So, *how to easily combine any amount of square matrices into one big square matrix?*

EDIT:

I came up with the following:

```
def plotimgs(ls):
    shp = ls[0].shape[0]         # the image's dimension
    dim = np.ceil(sqrt(len(ls))) # the amount of pictures per row AND column
    emptyimg = (ls[1]*0 + 1)*255 # used to add to the list to allow square matrix
    for i in range(int(dim*dim - len(ls))):
        ls.append(emptyimg)
    enddim = int(shp*dim)        # enddim by enddim is the final matrix dimension
    # Convert to 600x600 in the end to resize the pictures to fit the screen
    newimg = cv2.resize(np.reshape(ls, (enddim, enddim)), (600, 600))
    cv2.imshow("frame", newimg)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

 plotimgs([a,b,d])
```

Somehow, even though the dimensions are okay, it actually clones some pictures more:

> ```
> When I give 4 pictures, I get 8 pictures.
> When I give 9 pictures, I get 27 pictures.
> When I give 16 pictures, I get 64 pictures.
> ```

So in fact rather than squared, I get to the third power of images somehow. Though, e.g.

`plotimg([a]*9)` gives a picture with dimensions of `44*3 x 44*3 = 144x144` which should be correct for 9 images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that I use for doing this sort of thing:

```
import numpy as np

def montage(imgarray, nrows=None, border=5, border_val=np.nan):
    """
    Returns an array of regularly spaced images in a regular grid, separated
    by a border

    imgarray: 
        3D array of 2D images (n_images, rows, cols)
    nrows:  
        the number of rows of images in the output array. if 
        unspecified, nrows = ceil(sqrt(n_images))
    border: 
        the border size separating images (px)
    border_val:
        the value of the border regions of the output array (np.nan
        renders as transparent with imshow)
    """

    dims = (imgarray.shape[0], imgarray.shape[1]+2*border,
        imgarray.shape[2] + 2*border)

    X = np.ones(dims, dtype=imgarray.dtype) * border_val
    X[:,border:-border,border:-border] = imgarray

    # array dims should be [imageno,r,c]
    count, m, n = X.shape

    if nrows != None:
        mm = nrows
        nn = int(np.ceil(count/nrows))
    else:
        mm = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(count)))
        nn = mm

    M = np.ones((nn * n, mm * m)) * np.nan

    image_id = 0
    for j in xrange(mm):
        for k in xrange(nn):
            if image_id >= count: 
                break
            sliceM, sliceN = j * m, k * n
            img = X[image_id,:, :].T
            M[sliceN:(sliceN + n), sliceM:(sliceM + m)] = img
            image_id += 1

    return np.flipud(np.rot90(M))
```

**Example:**

```
from scipy.misc import lena
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = lena().astype(np.float32)
img -= img.min()
img /= img.max()
imgarray = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 25)[:, None, None] + img)

m = montage(imgarray)
plt.imshow(m, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

[image]

Comment: `imgarray = np.reshape(ls, (ls[0].shape[0], ls[0].shape[1], len(ls)))`, does not work, where ls is `[a,b,c,d]` in my case. -- Actually, it does work.

Comment: Ok so the montage creates from the input of `(300, 300, 4)`, where 4 represents the amount of pictures. It returns an image of size `(5580, 252)`. How does that work?

Comment: The first dimension of the input should be the number of images

Answer (score 0):

Reusing chunks from [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) :

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

Rewriting your function:

```
def plotimgs(ls):
    shp = ls[0].shape[0]         # the image's dimension
    dim = int(np.ceil(sqrt(len(ls)))) # the amount of pictures per row AND column
    emptyimg = (ls[1]*0 + 1)*255 # used to add to the list to allow square matrix
    ls.extend((dim **2 - ls) * [emptyimg]) # filling the list with missing images
    newimg = np.concatenate([np.concatenate(c, axis=0) for c in chunks(ls, dim)], axis=1)
    cv2.imshow("frame", newimg)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

 plotimgs([a,b,d])
```

Comment: It throws the "not an integer" error. Also, why do you `sqrt` the dim?